# how to run unit tests on packages that have changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, lerna

I am trying to use lerna (https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to manage my projects.

But one issue I am trying to find out is how to setup my test pipeline. 
If I only touch two projects, I would like only test cases from that two project will be executed.

But from what I read so far, seems like I will have to run all unit tests for all projects.

Does anyone have any idea how to execute on projects that changes only?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-when-changed

and write something like this for each package (taken from then npm page)

```
  $ run-when-changed \
  --watch "tests/**/*-test.js" \
  --exec "mocha --require babel-register %s" \
  --verbose
```

enter code here

But replace `tests/**/*-test.js` with the files in your package
And replace `mocha --require babel-register  %s` with a command running mocha on that specific package